# Converting input to a double in Java 1.4.2

Tags: java, input, double

there is a section in a school project where I need to convert input to a double, to be multiplied by another double, and I keep getting "error: int cannot be dereferenced" for the following code:

```
        int a = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
        int aa = a.nextInt();
        int aaa = Math.pow(1 + a, aa);
        amount1 = (aaa * 13.49);
        amount += amount1;
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: An `int` is a primitive, not an object.  This means you cannot call methods on it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call a method on an `int`, but you are trying:

```
a.nextInt();
```

Assuming that `input` is a `Scanner`, I think that you want to call `nextInt` on `input` instead.

**EDIT**

`Scanner` didn't exist in 1.4.2, so just do for `aa` what you already did for `a` -- parse the next line of input.

Comment: How do I fix this? I am new to Java.

Comment: Hint: Use the same for `aa` as you used for `a`

Comment: Also I can't use scanner, because I have to use Java 1.4.2, so instead I'm using BufferedReader

Comment: @user1965245 - You need to read the line into a String and then break it apart into successive pieces.  Apply parseInt to the pieces, not the entire string.

Comment: (And you can use String.split to break the line apart.)

Comment: Okay but the input will be a single whole number like 1,5,9 etc.

Comment: @user1965245 In that case use `String[] strArr= input.readLine().split(",")` `1,5,9 ` will get split on `,`

Comment: only 1 number will be entered at a time thought

Comment: @user1965245 - readLine doesn't return a value until the user hits the Enter key.

Comment: @user1965245 It will be better if you specify correctly how you are entering numbers. We are getting confused with your statements.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to understand without knowing the format you are reading: e.g If your input source has a single integer per line - simply repeat the first line

int aa = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());